# Raspberry PI プログラムの make で `undefined reference to symbol 'clock_gettime@@GLIBC_2.4'` エラー等が出る

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, makefile

「Interface 2014年 1月号, [ラズベリーパイ×カメラで本格派画像処理](http://shop.cqpub.co.jp/hanbai/books/MIF/MIF201401.html)」を読みながら、 Raspberry PI のカメラモジュールを OpenCV で動かそうとしています。

36ページの 「コンパイルと実行」のところを行っているのですが、 `CMakeLists.txt` を `cmake` した後に `＄make` しようとすると

```
Linking CXX executable simpleface
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/simpleface.dir/simpleface.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'clock_gettime@@GLIBC_2.4'
//lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/simpleface.dir/build.make:183: recipe for target 'simpleface' failed
make[2]: *** [simpleface] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:63: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/simpleface.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/simpleface.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

と出てしまい `make` 出来ません…

「[Think RPI:OpenCV and Pi Camera Board](https://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/opencv-and-pi-camera-board/)」のブログ記事も参照してみたのですが、やはり同じ様にエラーが出てしまいます。

どうすればよいか分かる方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

ライブラリに差がでてるように見えますので、とりあえず。。

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo rpi-update
$ sudo reboot
```

と実行してみて、再実行するのはのどうでしょう。(しばらく時間がかかります。)
手元では [Using OpenCV with gcc and CMake](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) は大丈夫でした。

ちなみに glibc のバージョンは以下のようになっています。

```
$ /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u6) stable release version 2.13, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.6.3.
Compiled on a Linux 3.2.51 system on 2015-01-11.
Available extensions:
        crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
        GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
        Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
        Support for some architectures added on, not maintained in glibc core.
        BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
$
```

### 追記

`2014-12-24-wheezy-raspbian.img` を使って綺麗な気持ちでやってみたところ、なんとなく出来てしまいました。

> (修正)最新の Raspbian を最初から使っているとなると、そもそも 2.13 がスタートなので、下記はまったくの妄想なので取り下げます。(どうやって、 OpenCV を入れているのか？と、 そもそもの `CMakeLists.txt` を見ないと判断できんような気がしてきました。。)

<s>やっていて気がついたのですが、雑誌が手元にないので想像になってしまいますが OpenCV をソースコードから make して導入しているのではないでしょうか？

であれば、エラーの原因は OpenCV のライブラリを作成した時の glibc のバージョンと、今の glibc のバージョンに矛盾がでてしまっているような状態が現状だと妄想します。</s>

他の依存ライブラリも影響しそうなので、OpenCV の make のタイミング以外にも問題があるかもしれないので、なんとも言えませんが、妄想が正しいのであれば、

一旦、[ここなど](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276169/removing-all-installed-opencv-libs#9278502) を参考にして、OpenCV を uninstall して、今の環境で再度 make しなおすか、作成するプログラムが [最新の機能](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog) に依らないのであれば Raspbian のバッケージ管理に任せてしまって、 `apt-get` にて 2.4.1 を使用することができます。(できました)

`apt-get` でいいなら、OpenCV の uninstall 後に、例えば、、

```
$ sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
$ sudo apt-get install cmake
```

などとすれば、、

```
$ mkdir opencv_test
$ cd opencv_test
$ vi DisplayImage.cpp
...
$ vi CMakeLists.txt
...
$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/opencv
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target DisplayImage
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable DisplayImage
[100%] Built target DisplayImage
$
```

(`DisplayImage.cpp` と `CMakeLists.txt` は上記 [Using OpenCV with gcc and CMake](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) のままです。)
みたいなことは出来るようになると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます、今から試してみて結果を共有致します！

Comment: 実行してみましたが、結果は同じでやはりmakeの段階で躓いてしまいました・・・

Comment: ざんねんです。。エラーメッセージや、'$ /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6' の結果に変化はないですか？

Comment: 特に変化は無いようです、OSなど新しいもの(2014-12-25 Rasbian)を用いているので、何か変更されてしまったのかもしれませんが初心者すぎてわからないのが現状です・・・

Comment: 新しい Rasbian に興味があったので、素から試してみて気がついたことを追記してみました。(こういった場合、回答を別にした方がよいのかしら。。)

Comment: ありがとうございます！色々とやっていたら別の問題が発生してしまってわけがわからなくなりました・・・その問題を解決したら、またこちらも試してみたいと思いますありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

[Realtime Extensions](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/realtime.html)を使っているようですが、CMakeLists.txtの設定でrtはリンク対象に入ってますでしょうか？
CMakeLists.txtに

```
target_link_libraries( ... rt ...)
```

のように、rtがなければRealtime Extensions(clock_gettime)は使えないと思います。

librt.so自体が存在するかどうかも一応確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます、上のコメントにも書いたのですが、別の問題が発生してしまったのでひとまずこちらの問題は保留にしてる段階になってます・・・コメントありがとうございます！
その問題が解決したらこちらも確認してみたいと思います！